# Need help understanding this HTTP GET request

Tags: c#, oauth, https, get

I am trying the construct a HTTP GET web request that satisfies the following criteria

```
 GET /v1/session  
 Host: developer.messenger.yahooapis.com  
 Authorization: < Standard OAuth credentials >
```

From what I know about get requests is that they are something like this :

```
https://someaddress.com/&parameterA=valA&parameterB=valB
```

where parameterA and parameterB are the parameters that are required.

Now I want to construct a similar address for the above mentioned criteria. How can I do that. I believe the address would be `https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com` however I am not sure what the other requirements are for such a get request. I would appreciate it if someone could disect and specify the requirements of the above(Topmost) Get Request so that I may be able to construct a valid GET request URI.

Comment: If you type http://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com/v1/session in your browser, you will see thats a valid address, what is the question here?

Comment: what does  Authorization: < Standard OAuth credentials > mean here ? is that a string ? Where should that be added to the uri ?

Comment: That means you have to provide authorization details in the header of the request. Google for authorization and OData.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com
so your request url should be like

https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com?parameterA=valA&parameterB=valB

you get your data in your $_GET array, just add print_r($_GET)

Comment: How do you know it takes two parameters ? parameterA and parameterB were just imaginary parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For a request, you need a URL like

```
https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com
```

*BUT* that is only the hostname.
you need to specify a resource that you want to `GET` like `/v1/session`, so your URL is

```
https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com/v1/session
```

If you want to pass some parameters you have to signal that the pointing part of the URL is finished. You do this with an `?`. Now to add the parameters, you basically add name-value pairs, like `var1=value`. For multiple params use a `&` to seperate them. Slapping all together you get a

```
https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com/v1/session?var1=value&var2=value
```

as URL. Now hand it to your HttpGet-method.

HttpGet will now build a `request` and later send it to `https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com` the host/server who will return the resource to your client. To tell the host that you have the rights to access that resource, the request must contain the neccessary login informations, thats what `oAuth` is for. Those credentials have to be added in the request header before executing the get-request.